# click nodes which are not parent at d3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I am stuck little bit stuck with a very simple d.3 problem..i have nodes with parent children relationship. I am trying to create a scenario where I will click all the node except the parent node

I am thinking something like this maybe?

```
.on(click, function(node){
  if(!= node.parent){
    window.location = d.url;
  }
})
```

which obviously doesnt work. What is the syntax for this?

This is how the returned json looks like. This will give an idea how am I seeing what is a parent and what are children

```
functiongetNodes(){
    varinNodes={
        "name": "Test App",
        "dept": "NYC",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "HPD Data Feeds",
                "dept": "Third Party",
                "category": "API",
                "size": 15,
                "url": "http://nycpdev.localhost:8082/api/hpd-data-feeds"
            },
            {
                "name": "DOT Data Feeds",
                "dept": "Third Party",
                "category": "API",
                "size": 15,
                "url": "http://nycpdev.localhost:8082/api/dot-data-feeds"
            },
            {
                "name": "HPD Data Feeds",
                "dept": "Third Party",
                "category": "App",
                "size": 15,
                "url": "http://nycpdev.localhost:8082/api/hpd-data-feeds"
            }
        ],
        "size": 20,
        "url": "app/113"
    };returninNodes;
}
```

Comment: What determines whether a node is a parent node or not?

Comment: @lars..just added the the json output..it will help you to understand how I am getting the children. Actually that "url": "app/113" is some type of garbage. I cant remove that. So basically trying not to click the parent at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get whether a node has children or not directly from the JSON:

```
.on(click, function(node){
  if(!node.children){
    window.location = d.url;
  }
})
```